# How to select JDBC / JPA implementations at run time?

Tags: java, jpa, optimization, jdbc

I'm writing an application meant to manage a database using **both JDBC and JPA** for an exam. I would like the user to select once at the beginning the API to use so that **all the application will use the selected API** (whether it be JPA or JDBC).

For the moment I decided to use this approach:

1. I created **an interface for each DAO class** (e.g. `interface UserDAO`) with all needed method declarations.
2. I created **two classes** for each DAO **distinguished by the API used** (e.g `UserDAOImplJDBC` and `UserDAOImplJPA`). Both of them implement the interface (in our case, `UserDAO`).
3. I created a third class (e.g. `UserDAOImpl`) that extends the JDBC implementation class. **In all my code I've been always using this class**. When I wanted to switch to the JPA I just had to change in all DAO classes the `extends ***ImplDAOJDBC` to `extends ***ImplDAOJPA`.

Now, as I'm starting having many DAO classes it's starting being complicate to modify the code each time.

Is there a way to change all `extends` faster? 
I was considering adding an option in the first screen (for example a `radioGroup`) to select JDBC or JPA. But yet I have no idea **how to make it work without having to restructure all code**. Any idea?

Comment: I recommend changing your approach. (1) Keep the `UserDAO`, `UserDAOImplJDBC` and `UserDAOImplJPA`. (2) Create a class and method `DaoProvider.getUserDao(Type t)` (or factory if you are creating new instances instead of reusing them) which is going to return the correct `UserDAO` based on the desired type (JPA or JDBC).

Comment: Ask your teacher as this really makes no sense, not even when the goal was a comparison of the two approaches. They're just too different and when you started with JDBC, then you won't be able to use most of JPA meaningfully. If you started with JPA, you'd have to simulate it using JDBC. Anyway, it won't be a meaningful comparison. And having two implementations in production is plain wasteful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a factory to get the appropriate DAO, every time you need one:

```
public class UserDaoFactory {
    public UserDao create() {
        if (SomeSharedSingleton.getInstance().getPersistenceOption() == JDBC) {
            return new UserDAOImplJDBC();
        }
        else {
            return new UserDAOImplJPA();
        }
    }
}
```

That's a classic OO pattern.

That said, I hope you realize that what you're doing there should really never be done in a real application:

- there's no reason to do the exact same thing in two different ways
- the persistence model of JPA and JDBC is extremely different: JPA entities are managed by the JPA engine, so every change to JPA entities is transparently made persistent. That's not the case with JDBC, where the data you get from the database is detached. So the way to implement business logic is very different between JPA and JDBC: you typically never need to save any change when using JPA.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me a lot. The real reason why I have to do it is because I've been asked to do so by my professor. I admit I haven't produced the JPA code yet, and I didn't realize it would have used different methods. What would you advice me to do? To create a new project starting from the JDBC one?

Comment: I don't know what your teacher wants you to do. I'm just saying that, in a real project, you wouldn't do the same thing in two different ways. You would use JPA everywhere, except maybe in some use cases that would be better implemented using JDBC, or you would use JDBC everywhere, but you wouldn't implement all use cases in two different ways. That would only introduce more complexity, more bugs, more development time, for 0 added value.

Answer (score 0):

You got 1 and 2 right, but 3 completely wrong.
Instead of having `Impl` extending one of the other implementations, choose which implementation to initialize using a utility method, for example. That's assuming you don't use Dependency Injection framework such as Spring.

```
UserDAO dao = DBUtils.getUserDAO();

public class DBUtils {

   public static boolean shouldUseJdbc() {
      // Decide on some configuration what should you use
   }

   public static UserDAO getUserDAO() {
      if (shouldUseJdbc()) {
          return new UserDAOImplJDBC();
      }
      else {
          return new UserDAOImplJPA();
      }
   }
}
```

This is still jus an examle, as your DAOs don't need to be instantiated each time, but actually should be singletons.